# How do I localize the names of menu items in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm creating localizations--in Spanish and Chinese--for a Sitecore site. The original language is English. I've learned how to create my language-specific versions of pages. But I don't know how to change the names of the the navigation items themselves. When I preview my pages in Spanish (http://content.example.com/?sc_lang=es), for example, the page content is in Spanish, but the navigation items themselves (e.g. Home, About, Products, etc.) are still in English. Where in the Content or Page editors do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the "display name" of the item in the Home ribbon. Be aware that this also affects the url of the item For the chosen language.

**Edit:** maybe I was too quick with my answer, I probably overread something cause my suggestion changes the Url (if you have the setting "useDisplayName=true" like jammykam corrected) and the name of the item in the content tree for the specific language.

If your the names displayed in the navigation is based on the Item names, then can do as I suggested, change the display item's name for the current language and make the code look at the display name inestead of the item name.

Another option is to use a separate field for the menu-title in case you want your titles to differ from your url's.

Comment: This solution worked for me. In the Content Editor, I select the node, select the language/version (i.e. Flag icon on top right), then choose the Home --> Rename --> Display Name option. It gets a little confusing, as Sitecore changes the node as well (in nav tree, on the left), temporarily, but it doesn't affect the URL (which, in my case, stays in English). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you say the navigation items themselves are in still in English, what do you mean? As in, the menu running along the top of the page?

If so, then you need to figure out where in the content tree those items are and then add in the relevant language versions/translations, and make sure they are not "shared" content.

@Martijn, I believe it only affects the URL is you set "useDisplayName=true" in the linkManager setting in config.

Answer (score 0):

We usually add a field called MenuTitle to the base content template and then instruct our navigation controls to read from that field

Answer (score 0):

For menus, we generally use a different field for the page's title and the page's navigation title.  This allows for a shorter version to be specified by the author for the menu.

Once you have that, you just need to make sure you build code in your header control to find the target item of the menu link (I assume it's a general link, or some other Item reference) and pull the target item's navigation title.

When the code does this, it should automatically pull the version of that target item based on the current language, which will mean you will get your navigation title in the correct language.